# Remove file name extensions AND redirect from www to non-www with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My domain name is *https:*//example.com - I'm working with my .htaccess to remove the file extensions from the URL, so *https:*//example.com/pages/file.php is getting displayed as *https:*//example.com/pages/file, which is working fine.

I'm now having some problems with duplicate content and would like to redirect *https:*//www.example.com/pages/file to *https:*//example.com/pages/file. My current .htaccess looks like the following (it placed once in root directory **and** once the subdirectory /pages/):

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
 RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

The problem is, by accessing *https:*//www.example.com/pages/file, I'm getting redirected to *https:*//example.com/file, so without the /pages/ part, which is very important as all subpages are stored into that directory. I don't know if it's important, but i got some header.php and footer.php files in my root directory which need to be accessable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move this rule:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

To the top, just below these rules:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should cause the urls with "/pages/" to be redirected correctly

Comment: After moving the rules you mentioned to a higher position, it was (sadly) still not working. When trying to access https://example.com/pages/website, i got redirected to https://example.com/website. Do you think there could be a problem with having two .htaccess files (one in the root and one in the /pages/ directory)? Thanks for your help, @Nadir Latif

Comment: @Niclas you can try to remove the .htaccess file from the pages directory to see if it helps.